# Not splitting test set and just using competition public score

Tags: cross-validation, boosting

With relatively small (~700) training set, would it be better if I train model with XGboost+k-fold validation and just use public score to evaluate the model's performance on unseen data? I wonder if splitting out test set initially adds any value, especially on small data set. Is there any gain from testing model on internal test set and testing again with public score?

Comment: Welcome to CV! What do you mean by public score?

Comment: @FransRodenburg   Hi! thank you for the welcome. I should have mentioned Kaggle competition. They show public score (usually some sort of accuracy measure) from about half of test set and those are used for leaderboard. At the end of competition, the final ranking is determined by how well the model did on the other half of test set, so people overfitting to public score usually don't do well in the end.